# CentOS server freezing daily

Tags: centos, cpanel, pure-ftpd

Host: CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

Server is freezing on a daily basis, usually around 5am. I cannot login to the terminal, and the Apache websites are inaccessible.

Terminal shows following screen:

[image: Terminal]

Last logs in /var/logs/messages. Could the issue be related to cpanel and/or pure-ftpd?

```
Sep 16 05:20:11 cpanel02 lfd[4548]: SYSLOG check [yyx5o4oClslObXL]
Sep 16 05:20:32 cpanel02 kernel: [161487.262762] Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.214.22 DST=5.9.124.53 LEN=191 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=33282 DPT=24441 LEN=171 UID=0 GID=0
Sep 16 05:20:34 cpanel02 pure-ftpd: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] New connection from 127.0.0.1
Sep 16 05:20:34 cpanel02 pure-ftpd: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] __cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__wnN9amQ1oxAGrn6WrdHNL1rXSkYwQ4wsRStiOtyrYRodnvmU0JQ9JiEe3113xkDw is now logged in
Sep 16 05:20:34 cpanel02 pure-ftpd: (__cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__wnN9amQ1oxAGrn6WrdHNL1rXSkYwQ4wsRStiOtyrYRodnvmU0JQ9JiEe3113xkDw@127.0.0.1) [INFO] Logout.
Sep 16 05:25:33 cpanel02 kernel: [161788.373406] Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.214.22 DST=5.9.124.53 LEN=192 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=34193 DPT=24441 LEN=172 UID=0 GID=0
Sep 16 05:25:35 cpanel02 pure-ftpd: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] New connection from 127.0.0.1
Sep 16 05:25:35 cpanel02 pure-ftpd: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] __cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__Lcv6XAStC8q6sSKCi6qb6O4ipL63PO4e3VCNOhdcxXpAjA1FGaPSu2I1OM1nXSlw is now logged in
Sep 16 05:25:35 cpanel02 pure-ftpd: (__cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__Lcv6XAStC8q6sSKCi6qb6O4ipL63PO4e3VCNOhdcxXpAjA1FGaPSu2I1OM1nXSlw@127.0.0.1) [INFO] Logout.
Sep 16 05:30:12 cpanel02 lfd[4548]: SYSLOG check [xfL4KehGAgdKefc8]
Sep 16 05:30:35 cpanel02 kernel: [162089.570555] Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.214.22 DST=5.9.124.53 LEN=191 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=53415 DPT=24441 LEN=171 UID=0 GID=0
Sep 16 05:30:36 cpanel02 pure-ftpd: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] New connection from 127.0.0.1
Sep 16 05:30:36 cpanel02 pure-ftpd: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] __cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__1pmBiVuVLkyHFRZMAfB9aGpX5Z0akRMPNd0Wp9l49I6Raa6Dcp5C0YpI3V2js2sn is now logged in
Sep 16 05:30:36 cpanel02 pure-ftpd: (__cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__1pmBiVuVLkyHFRZMAfB9aGpX5Z0akRMPNd0Wp9l49I6Raa6Dcp5C0YpI3V2js2sn@127.0.0.1) [INFO] Logout.
```

Comment: Please don't post images, post text instead.

Comment: I would have, but I couldn't copy/paste the text.

Comment: I would not argue about causality just because the logs show that last.  I'd try the following: after restarting the machine (and without performing any suspends/sleeps/etc) i'd run `dmesg` and `dmesg -T`, comparing the output of both I can get the relation between the kernel timer and the hardware clock.  Then when it hangs again I'll be able to tell exactly when it happened in time, based on the hang screen and previous noted relation.  I can then check the logs about what happens at that time.

Comment: Normally "blocked for more than 120 seconds" indicates some sort of storage problem. What is your storage setup on this server? Also, is this a VM or not? (On a VM, it can also mean the physical server is overloaded). I'd see about leaving an `iostat -kx 10` running and seeing if anything weird happens around the same time.